# Why does my dropdown don't extend fully on my page?

Tags: html, css

I have a dropdown menu which I wanted it to extend full width on my page. I just started styling my dropdown (dropdown functionality not yet working). I already set my width to 100% and it still broken. Is this because i have a page wrapper which has 1024px in width? This wrapper is used to make all the contents center and vertically aligned. I am having a really hard time and this already took me hours and hours of debugging and I can't still find what's wrong with my code.

```
<div id ="lower-header">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="images/logo/logo_01.png">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">KU 스타트업</a>
                    <!--dropdown  menu-->
                    <div class="sub-menu-whole">
                            <!--<img src="images/bg/bg_submenu_01.png">-->
                        <div class="column">
                            <ul id="sub-list">
                                <li class="sub-list-item">
                                    <a class="sub-list-title">인사말</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="sub-list-item">
                                    <a class="sub-list-title">창업부서소개</a>
                                    <ul class="sub-sub-list">
                                        <li class="item"><a class="sub-sub-title">크림슨창업지원단</a></li>
                                        <li class="item"><a class="sub-sub-title">기술지주회사</a></li>
                                        <li class="item"><a class="sub-sub-title">스타트업 연구원</a></li>
                                        <li class="item"><a class="sub-sub-title">캠퍼스타운지원센터</a></li>
                                        <li class="item"><a class="sub-sub-title">KU개척마을</a></li>
                                        <li class="item"><a class="sub-sub-title">기술사업부</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="column">
                            <ul id="sub-list">
                                <li class="sub-list-item">
                                    <a class="sub-list-title">창업 비전</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="sub-list-item">
                                    <a class="sub-list-title">찾아오시는 길</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="column">
                            <ul id="sub-list">
                                <li class="sub-list-item">
                                    <a class="sub-list-title">창업 프로세스</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>                              
                    </div>
                    <!--//end of dropdown contents-->
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">프로그램</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">스타트업 리더</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">창업보육</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">창업멘토단</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">커뮤니티</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS code: (used SASS for my css)

```
.wrapper { /*wrapper*/
        width: 1024px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

#lower-header {
background-color: #ffffff;
height: 100px;
position: relative;
width: -webkit-fill-available;
z-index: 1;
    img {
        float: left;
        margin-top: 33px;
    }

    ul {
        list-style: none;
        display: block;
        float: left;
        margin: 17px 0px;
        padding-left: 30px;

        li {                
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 17px;
            font-weight: bold;
            padding: 16px 19px;
            height: 73px;

                    .sub-menu-whole {
                        background-color: #ffffff;
                        height: 360px; 
                        position: absolute;
                        z-index: 1;
                        width: 100%;
                        border-top: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
                        border-bottom: 1px solid #760023;
                            &:after {
                                content: "";
                                display: table;
                                clear: both;
                            }
                        img {
                            margin:0;
                        }

                       .column {
                            float: left;
                            width: 33.33%;
                            border: 1px solid red;
                            margin: 0;

                            #sub-list { /*sub-list*/
                                .sub-list-item { /*sub-list-item*/
                                    background-color: #f3efed;
                                    height: auto;
                                    padding: 8px 10px 8px 10px;
                                    border: 1px solid #ede8e6;
                                    display: block;
                                    margin: 22px 0;
                                    width: 213px;
                                        &:hover {
                                            background-color: #414141;
                                            border-color: #3b3b3b;
                                            a {
                                            color: #ffffff;
                                            }
                                            .sub-sub-title { color: black; }
                                        }
                                    .sub-list-title {
                                        color: #766955;
                                        font-size: 15px;
                                        }
                                    .sub-sub-list {
                                            list-style: none;
                                            display:block;
                                            padding: 0;
                                        .item {
                                                display: block;
                                                /* margin: 0; */
                                                padding: 3px;
                                                height: auto;
                                            &:before {
                                                content: "-";
                                                color: #e2d5d3;
                                                margin-right: 8px;
                                                margin-left: -12px;
                                            }
                                            a {

                                                font-size: 13px;
                                                color: #535353;
                                            }   
                                        }
                                    }
                                } /*END OF SUBLIST ITEM*/
                            }  /*end of sublist*/
                       }  /*end of column*/
                    } /*end of sub-menu-whole*/
            a {
                text-decoration: none;
                color: #000000;

                &:hover {
                    color: red;
                }                   
            }
        } /*end of list*/
    } /*end of UL*/
} /*end of lower header*/
```

I wanted my dropdown to extend full width and what happened was the dropdown is a full width but the position is not at the other edge of the page.

Comment: can you explain exactly what you want:https://jsfiddle.net/awL486yn/

Comment: I want to have a dropdown menu but this must be a mega menu. and it seems that my dropdown is full width but there is a problem of the <div> position

Answer (score 1):

From what I can assess
Provide `width: 100vw;` and do not forget to `position: absolute;` along with `left: 0;` 
This could solve your problem.

**Update:** I just reviewed code again `display: inline-block;` and `width: 100%;` might also work, but you will still need to position it `left: 0;`

Comment: This saved my life! Thank you for answering my question! You are truly a life saver!!!!

Comment: Anytime !! If this has helped you, please accept the answer and upvote. Thanks !